# Organising .libs in a codebase of several C++ projects

Tags: c++

Let's say you have several bespoke C++ projects in separate repositories or top-level directories in the same repository. Maybe 10 are library projects for stuff like graphics, database, maths, etc and 2 are actual applications using those libraries.

What's the best way to organise those 2 application projects to have the .libs they need?

- Each lib project builds the .lib in its own directory, developers have to copy these across to the application area manually and make sure to get the right version
- Application projects expect lib projects to be in particular paths and look for .libs inside those locations
- A common /libs directory is used by all projects
- Something else

This is focused on C++, but I think it's pretty similar with other languages, for instance organising JARs in a Java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this approach:

Organise your code in a root folder. Let's call it code.

Now put your projects and libraries as subfolders (e.g. Projects and Libraries).

Build your libraries as normal and add a post-build step that copies the resulting headers and .lib files into a set of shared folders. For example, Libraries\include and Libraries\lib. It's a good idea to use subfolders or a naming convention (myLib.lib, myLib_d.lib) to differentiate different builds (e.g. debug and release) so that any lib reference explicitly targets a single file that can never be mixed up. It sucks when you accidentally link against the wrong variant of a lib!

You can also copy third-party libraries that you use into these folders as well.

Note: To keep them organised, include your files with #include "Math\Utils.h" rather than just "Utils.h". And put the headers for the whole Math library into include\Math, rather than dropping them all in the root of the include folder. This way you can have many libraries without name clashes. It also lets you have different versions of libraries (e.g. Photoshop 7, Photoshop 8) which allows you to multi-target your code at different runtime environments.

Then set up your projects to reference the libraries in one of two ways:

1) Tell your IDE/compiler where the libs are using its global lib/include paths. This means you set up the IDE once on each PC and never have to specify where the libs are for any projects.

2) Or, set each project to reference the libs with its own lib/include paths. This gives you more flexibility and avoids the need to set up every PC, but means you have to set the same paths in every new project.

(Which is best depends on the number of projects versus the number of developer PCs)

And the most important part: When you reference the includes/libs, use *relative* paths. e.g. from Projects\WebApp\WebApp.proj, use "..\..\Libraries\include" rather than "C:\Code\Libraries\Include". This will allow other developers and your buildserver to have the source code elsewhere (D:\MyWork instead of C:\Code) for convenience. If you don't do this, it'll bite you one day when you find a developer without enough disk space on C:\ or if you want to branch your source control.

Comment: *"When you reference the includes/libs, use relative paths"* ... prefer to put `../../Libraries/Include` into the projects include directories instead of referring to headers explicitly. That avoids breaking code if you decide to move the includes.

Comment: What happens when AppX uses the HEAD version of DatabaseUtils but AppY doesn't work against any revision later than r1234 of the same project? Your solution works ok when I want to have say boost1.2.3 and boost1.2.4 as separate projects - they release them like that. But often a utility project is still in development and new changes break functionality on older applications.

Comment: @gf: What I meant was that ./../Libraries/Include is in your INCLUDE_PATH, but your #include will then use subfolders for different libs, i.e. #include "Math\Utils.h". Otherwise you have to put a million headers in a single folder and you end up with many files with name clashes (like "types.h" being used in each library for different things)

Comment: @John: When using libraries, use unit tests to make sure you do not introduce regressions. In addition, avoid working with two ir more internal versions of libraries where possible - just keep all your projects working on the samed version and yu'll save a lot of pain. If you *must* use different versions, then branch your code in source control - that's what it's for.

Comment: (Remember that you don't control versions of boost, but you **do** control your own Libraries)

Comment: In a big codebase, an application may no longer be in development, or you may not control when it is released to the client. You may need to modify a utility library without being able to (or allowed to) update the old project accordingly.

Comment: Branches all pointing ata  single \libraries folder is the issue. One single libraries folder will always have the newest builds.

Comment: Why break branching by only branching half your code? If you branch your shared repository, and all references to it are *relative* so that each branch is a standalone snapshot of the codebase, then there's no problem.